# Post to own business Facebook Page without user login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to post to my business facebook pages through a desktop application (vb.net). The app is used by myself to update some text to be published on a digital signage TV (this works fine) and also automatically publish the text to my FB Page.

I used the Graph API Explorer to generate the app user access token (with manage_pages and publish_pages permission) and a page access token for the app.

Using FB's Access Token Debugger I was able to generate a never expiring Page Access Token. I also see that the scopes for it are: manage_pages, pages_show_list, publish_pages, public_profile

In "Development mode" I'm able to POST successfully to the business page by simply using the URL:

> [https://graph.facebook.com/{my-business-page-id}/feed?message=TEST_MESSAGE&access_token={my_non_expiring_page_access_token}](https://graph.facebook.com/%7Bmy-business-page-id%7D/feed?message=TEST_MESSAGE&access_token=%7Bmy_non_expiring_page_access_token%7D)

In "Live" mode unfortunately the above POST request returns the error:

> message:
>   (#200) Requires either publish_actions permission, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission"
>   type:"OAuthException"
>   code:200

My questions:

- Is there something I'm missing to the get the app "LIVE" with appropriate access permissions to publish?
- How can I avoid FB review (I'm the administrator of the app and also the administrator of the business page)?

Answer (score 0):

"Is there something I'm missing to the get the app "LIVE" with appropriate access permissions to publish?"

You need to pass a FB review which is not easy. Actually, it is now about impossible as Facebook says "On August 1st, 2018, the Live API publish_actions permission, which allows an app to publish on behalf of its Users, will be reserved for approved partners. In the coming weeks, a new permission model that allows apps to publish Videos to their User's Groups and Timelines will be announced" at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes

"How can I avoid FB review (I'm the administrator of the app and also the administrator of the business page)?"

You used to not need a FB review for this case but they seem to have changed their rules recently. So you used to only need a FB review to do stuff for users who didn't create the app. In fact, at the moment, it is failing for an app in development mode as well which is *real* annoying. (They changed their rules again 13 hours go.)